# Как подключить виртуальный numpad(JS) на сайт?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

На сайте есть форма заполнения, когда юзер нажимает на текстовое поле, то появляется виртуальная клавиатура, но есть и поля для ввода чисел, например тел. номер и ИИН пользователя, так вот нашел в интернете NUMPAD JS, но не могу ее подключить, я проверял, оно рабочее, но именно на моем сайте не работает

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.keypad.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.keypad.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#defaultKeyboard').keypad();
    $('#inlineKeypad').keypad({onClose: function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    }});
});
</script>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard.user.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keyboard.css">



<main class="main" style="padding:0; overflow-x:initial">
    <div class="container">
        {include file="engine/modules/products/eogpo.php"}
    </div>
</main>
<div id="isTerminal"></div>

<div id="modalError" class="modal info__modal" data-modal>
    <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close">
        <svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="modalStyle">
        <h3 class="info__title" id="errorTitle"><?php echo _("Ошибка"); ?></h3>
        <div id="textError"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modalInfo" class="modal info__modal" data-modal>
    <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close">
        <svg class="icon icon-close"><use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg#icon-close"></use></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="modalStyle">
        <div id="textInfo"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="overLoader" style="display: none"><img src="/templates/assets/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

подключил скрипты в `.tpl`, `keyboard.user.js` и `keyboard.css` это от виртуальной клавиатуры, они работают нормально, вот скрипты выше от NUMPAD, они не работают, вроде все сделал по туториалу, может скрипты конфликтуют друг с другом, но я отключал скрипты клавиатуры и проверял, но без изменении, может быть какие либо другие конфликты могут быть, кто нибудь может объяснить проблему?

```
<!-- ИИН -->
<fieldset class="field-set col col--4-12" style="false">
<label for="orderIIN" class="field-set__label checkList">
<?php echo _("ИИН");?>
</label>
<input class=" field iin-masked datas" id="defaultKeyboard" type="text" name="IIN[]"  maxlength="12" />
<span class="small col" id="textKBM0"></span>
<span class="small col" id="loadingIIN0"></span>
<input class="datas" id="KBM0" type="hidden" name="KBM[]" value="" />
<input class="datas" id="clientID0" type="hidden" name="clientID[]" value="" />
<input class="datas" id="clientISN0" type="hidden" name="clientISN[]" value="" />
<input class="datas" id="clientNation0" type="hidden" name="clientNation[]" value="Казахстан" />
                </fieldset>

<!-- Резидент -->
<fieldset class="field-set col col--4-12 classResident ">
<label for="orderResident" class="field-set__label checkList">
<?php echo _("Резидент") ?>
</label>
<div class="radio-button-group">
    <label class="radio-button">
<input type="radio" class="radio-button__input radioResident datas" name="resident0[]" id="residentY0" value="Y" />
<span class="radio-button__label"><?php echo _("Резидент"); ?></span>
</label>
<label class="radio-button">
<input type="radio" class="radio-button__input radioResident datas" name="resident0[]" id="residentN0" value="N" />
<span class="radio-button__label"><?php echo _("Нерезидент"); ?></span>
</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

форма заполнения

Comment: может он конфликтует с джейквери, версия или символ $

Comment: @VitaliyScherban с каким именно джейквери вы думаете оно конфликтует? я проверял этот скрипт на работоспособность, и там она нормально работает

Comment: с самым обычным

Comment: я бы использовал эту https://virtual-keyboard.js.org/